# Subdomain should access all the main domain files, except config database

Tags: codeigniter, subdomain

I am looking for the solution, as I am creating an application using CodeIgniter. I just want to create the user of that application having their own DB. I just want the way how to access the main directory application using subdomain.

Please provide solution I am totally lost and can't find the proper path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's multifaceted and theres a lot to do. Luckily for you there's a great tutorial here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/basecamp-style-subdomains-with-codeigniter/ Explains everything you need to do. Once you get going you can ask more specific questions.

Comment: I have tried the same but it wont work in my windows configuration.I am using windows platform and wamp server but it shows and mis-configuration error of server i have tried first three steps as it is but did not find any 
> If you are using Windows, browse to the directory 

    C:\Program
    > Files\system32\drivers\etc

 and open the hosts file in Notepad, or your
> preferred text editor. Add four entries, shown above, and save the
> file. If you’ve made DNS changes to a live server, it will take a
> while before you notice any effect. If you made changes to your hosts